# iOS Facebook SDK delegate methods not called

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-oauth

I see this question asked in several other posts but nothing seems to work for me. After following the [FB login guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) I had a working prototype that would allow users to authenticate with FB. However this guide instructs you place all FB OAuth logic directly into the AppDelegate and that is not ideal for me since I will support more than just FB authentication. So what I have done is move the login logic into it's own class. Since then it seems that the FB delegate methods do not get called after a user successfully authenticates with FB and control should be passed back to my application.

I have a modal login view which takes my FacebookAuth class as a delegate. When I attempt to create a session the FB login page appears and I authorize my application. After that no other delegate methods are called. Can anyone provide some hints?

```
 @interface FacebookAuth()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) User *sessionUser;
    @end

    @implementation FacebookAuth

    @synthesize sessionIsOpen = _sessionIsOpen;
    @synthesize sessionUser = _sessionUser;


    -(id)initWithViewDelegate:(id<AuthorizationViewDelegate>)viewDelegate
    {
        NSAssert(viewDelegate != nil, @"FacebookAuth must be initialized with a view delegate.");
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            self.viewDelegate = viewDelegate;
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
          self = [self initWithViewDelegate:nil];
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(BOOL)sessionIsOpen{
        return (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen);
    }


    -(void)requestSessionUserWithSuccess:(void (^)(User *))success Failure:(void (^)(NSError *))error{
        if(!self.sessionIsOpen){
            error([NSError errorWithDomain:@"Session Closed" code:0 userInfo:nil]);
            return;
        }
        if(self.sessionUser == nil){
            [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
             ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
               NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
               NSError *err) {
                 if (!err) {
                     User *ses_user = [[User alloc]initWithId:user.id first:user.first_name last:user.last_name sessionToken:  [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken]];
                     self.sessionUser = ses_user;
                     success(ses_user);
                 } else{
                     error(err);
                 }
             }];
        } else{
            success(self.sessionUser);
        }

    }

    -(void)openSession
    {
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:
         ^(FBSession *session,
           FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
             [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
         }];
    }

    -(void)closeSession{
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        self.sessionUser = nil;
        self.sessionIsOpen = NO;
    };



-(void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:{
            self.sessionIsOpen = YES;
            [self.viewDelegate loginSuccess];
        }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:{
            self.sessionIsOpen = NO;
        }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:{
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
             self.sessionIsOpen = NO;
            [self.viewDelegate loginFailure:error];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

I apologize for the large code snippet but I don't want to leave out anything that may be valuable in assisting.

After calling

> -(void)openSession:

The facebook authentication page appears and I authorize the application. After that I was expecting the FB delegate method to be called:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
```

It never is. Do I need to declare this class as a type of FB delegate? I am using the latest Facebook SDK available.

Any help would be great.